# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0.txt'

Tags: python

I am writing a program to read a set of text files from folder "set" to a list.My code for this is

```
def get_documents():
    path1 = "D:/set/"
    texts = []
    listing1 = os.listdir(path1)
    for file in listing1:
        with open(file,'r') as f:
            lines = f.read().splitlines()
            texts.append(lines)
```

But this gives me Error as

```
with open(file,'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0.txt'
```

There are text files inside `D:/set/` namely `0.txt,1.txt,2.txt...`
What is the reason for this Error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `os.listdir()` returns the file names in the directory and not the full path which is expected by `open()`.

You can solve it by joining the base path to the file name.

```
with open(os.path.join(path1, file),'r') as f:
    ...
```

Another alternative is to use `glob()` to avoid paths joining:

```
import glob
path1 = "D:/set/*"
listing1 = glob.glob(path1)
for file in listing1:
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        ...
```